# How to view a lombok generated class

Tags: lombok

Using Lombok to generate code with Eclipse/Maven. Would like to be able to view in text the class which is being generated. Hunted around under target but did not see anything. Is there a way to have Lombok output the generated class?

Comment: Are you looking for a Eclipse/Maven specific answer or  a general one? If second is the case see [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok)

Answer (score 3):

In intellij you can do:
Refactor (class) -> delombok -> All lombok annotation

[image]

Comment: OP asked for Eclipse/Maven. Also, Delombok doesn't just let you view the generated code, it turns your entire codebase into a Lombok-free one by modifying your source code directly and adding tons of generated code.

Comment: As @Christoph pointed out using delombok is not what OP asked for and massively causes unwanted effects.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221035/how-to-get-lombok-generated-source-to-be-visible-in-eclipse-maven) in eclipse you can see the signature of the lombok generated methods in the outline view. Shortcut: highlight the lombok annotated type and press ctrl-o. You can also open an outline view permanently with window/show view/outline.

BTW: In intellij-idea with the lombok annotated type highlighted you can press shift twice to open the search all dialog. The .class resource is the first item in the search result list. If you select that item a tab opens with the decompiled code.

In both cases it is mandatory of course, that lombok generation (for example with maven) took place beforehand.