# How to get lombok generated source to be visible in eclipse/maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I am attempting to use lombok (https://projectlombok.org/) to help with "boilerplate" code generation. I have added the maven dependency and have also added the lombok maven plugin to the `<build>` element in the POM.

One of the things I was also told to do was to place the lombok-annotated code in `src/main/lombok` instead of `src/main/java`. I assume that I keep the package directory structure the same as in `src/main/java`.

This seems a little odd, but I did this and lombok did generate source files with all the getter/setter/equals/hashCode etc methods. They are placed in e.g. `target/generated-sources/lombok/x/y/z/MyClass.java`. This is kind of what I would expect having used other code generation tools like XJC.

My question is: how do I get this generated source to be "visible" to eclipse and the compile environment? I'm getting compile errors all over the place because it can't "see" the generated code. This occurs in eclipse as well as when I attempt to do a `mvn clean install`.

**UPDATE**:

I have already tried installing lombok into eclipse. It generates the getters/setters/etc, but there is a bug introduced somewhere that breaks the auto-complete feature of eclipse. I removed it from eclipse and am just trying to get maven to do the generation (or delombok-ing).

Comment: Where did you get the src/main/lombok idea from? That sounds really bad. Did you follow e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide on how to install lombok and set it up in the IDE?

Comment: See https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Comment: From the maven plugin site. http://anthonywhitford.com/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/usage.html. I agree it sounds strange.

Comment: @howlger "See projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse" Been there, done that. That's a different story that I posted a question to the Lombok google group. I installed it into eclipse and it nicely generated the code and it was visible - but it introduced a problem where the eclipse auto-completion was broken under certain situations.

Comment: @JosephGagnon That's the _"I was also told..."_, right? If yes, please add a link to the Lombok google group where you was told so.

Comment: The posting on the Lombok Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/0mvDpPmj6yc

Comment: @JosephGagnon The primary issue might be caused by a Lombok version that is even older than your outdated Eclipse version.

Comment: @JosephGagnon that is not *the* maven plugin site, that is "one random person" on the internet. There is **no need** to use the plugin at all.

Answer (score 2):

I've just installed Lombok (after a while) in my new Eclipse (STS) installation, and i was a bit "annoyed" by the lack of generated sources.

I found a hint however [on this page](https://howtodoinjava.com/automation/lombok-eclipse-installation-examples/) that the generated structure is visible in the "Outline" view. (Look for the screenshots)

If you don't have Outline view open yet, enable it in the menu: Window / Show view / Outline.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable annotation processing for Eclipse to be able to pick up generated code.

1. Right-click on the project and select `Properties`.
2. Open `Java Compiler` and then `Annotation Processing`. Check `Enable
   annotation processing`.
3. Open `Java Compiler` -> `Annotation Processing` -> `Factory Path`. Check
   `Enable project specific settings`. Add your Lombok JAR file to the list.
4. Clean and build the project.

Comment: Tried this, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Download Lombok jar (https://projectlombok.org/download) and execute it `java -jar lombok.jar` and select your eclipse installed folder.Restart eclipse and rebuild project.

To verify Lombok installation,  please check Help -> About eclipse. Lombok entry show show at bottom.

[image]

Comment: Already been down that road. The problem described above occurs after that.

Comment: if ur are seeing compilation errors means lombok  plugin is not properly added to eclipse... Are you using @Data?. COuld you please check Help -> About eclipse..At the bottom Lombok entry should show.

Comment: Yes, Help -> About Eclipse shows the same information as what's shown in the image. BTW - how do I embed am image in SO?

Comment: did u executed Project -> clean ?..make sure to select build automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was using full namespace annotation: `@lombok.Getter`, and I resolved it by doing `import lombok.Getter` and do `@Getter`